# Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2

Tags: ruby

Não consigo rodar o `bundle install` no meu projeto, quando rodo aparece `Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2`.

Porem eu ja fiz um `rbenv local 2.2.2`e quando rodo o `rbenv version` ele me retorna `2.2.2 (set by /Users/...`, se ele fala que ja estou no `2.2.2` então porque ele não roda o `bundle install`?

**Obs.:** Não gostaria de alterar o `Gemfile`.

Comment: Com o comando ruby -version, retorna qual valor?

Comment: Desentalei tudo e instalei de novo e funcionou :S @DouglasGaldino  mto obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Delete o gemfile.lock e de bundle install veja o que acontece.

Caso não resolva tente procurar no gemfile.lock essa versão de ruby, pode ser que alguma gem especifica ela.